# 3 Phase Voltage Imbalance

Tags: three-phase

We're trying to setup rotary phase converter, and we're getting some differences in line voltage. The black reads 350 to ground while red and white read 120 to ground. This is all from a 220 input. Red to white reads at 240 volts. Any thoughts on the problem? I don't imagine this is normal.

Comment: Why do you measure to ground? Don't you have neutral?

Comment: Make and model of the rotary phase converter? Photo of nameplate? Is the 220 V the single-phase input? (If so it's probably irrelevant as the output would be isolated.) Have you got a load on it? Is there a wiring diagram on the machine? Please put all the required information into your question.

Comment: Seems a bit like a high-leg delta, but with some internal mis-wiring of the L1-L2 (red/white) phases.

Comment: Do red-black and white-black both read 240V?

Comment: We bought it with the CNC mills and it looks like a home brew type converter, so no name plate unfortunately.

Comment: red to black and white to black read 350. Red to white reads 240 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rotary phase converter's output is wired for [high-leg delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-leg_delta)
[image]
then I'll present the following as a possibility.

When wired correctly, you'd expect to see something like this when measuring from each phase to neutral:
[image]
and your measurements would be L1 & L2 = 120V, L3 = 208V.

However, if your phase converter is internally miswired like this:
[image]
then your result could look something like this instead:
[image]
and your measurements would be something like L1 & L2 = 120V, L3 = 317V.
So - not the 350V you're seeing, but maybe a possibility?

Comment: That could be the case... So I would just have to rewire the coils to the legs?

Comment: In theory - yes ...